# Regex to get number and string after number

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the number and the unit after the number from two different strings.. some strings have space between number and unit like this `150 g`  and others don't `150g`

```
$text = 'Rexona Ap Deo Aerosol 150ml Active CPD-05923';
$text='Cutex Nail Polish Remover Moisture 100ml ';

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $text, $matches);


    if(sizeof($matches[0]) > 1){
       // how can I extract 'ml'
      }
    else {
        // how can I extract 150 ml ?

    }
```

Can you guys please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('~\b(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s*(ml|gm?|kg|cm)\b~i', $text, $matches);
```

And use matched groups #1 and #2.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK9sV9/1)

Comment: What if the number was float like 1.5Kg what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
preg_match_all('!(\d+\s?\S+)!', $text, $matches);
```

- **\d+** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times
- **\s?** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

  - Quantifier: **?** Between zero and one time
- **\S+** match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]

  - Quantifier: **+** Between one and unlimited times